# xcode 5.0: Undefined symbols for architecture i386

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode5, undefined-symbol

I have done a lot of research but i didn't find any helpful thing.

I have following problem.

I am trying to make an app for school. till now it is working fine on simulator and on my iPhone 4 and on my iPad 3.
i have imported the 'RestKit' project to use it for the connection with my restful web service. (imported it with cocoa pods)

now i wanted to test it on the simulator on the 64-bit device (iPhone 5S)

but since i have added an open source project (ZBarSDK) for an QR-Code Reader i am getting this error.

> Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
>   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AFHTTPClient", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in TDOFTDatabase.o   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_RKObjectManager", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in TDOFTDatabase.o   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_RKObjectMapping", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in TDOFTDatabase.o   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_RKResponseDescriptor", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in TDOFTDatabase.o   "_RKMIMETypeJSON", referenced from:
>         -[TDOFTDatabase init] in TDOFTDatabase.o   "_RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass", referenced from:
>         -[TDOFTDatabase writeUser:] in TDOFTDatabase.o
>         -[TDOFTDatabase getMyID] in TDOFTDatabase.o
>         -[TDOFTDatabase loadAllDepartments] in TDOFTDatabase.o
>         -[TDOFTDatabase loadStations:atPos:] in TDOFTDatabase.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386 clang: error: linker command
>   failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: Did the app work with `ZBarSDK` before you tried it on the new device?  Does your school teach the scientific method?

Comment: Make sure you follow the step-by-step walk through for `ZBarSDK` on how to use it.  It's very simple to set up.  Also... it's hard to test the bar code scanner on the simulator... anyway, also keep in mind `ZBarSDK` has a memory leak in iOS7 at least... so find the StackOverflow post that addresses this fix at some point.

Comment: yes the app is working on all other devices except the 64-Bit devices.
no the school doesn't teach Objective-C or iPhone programming.

Comment: Did it work on the 64-bit device before `ZBarSDK`?  If you take `ZBarSDK` completely out, will it work on the 64-bit device?

Comment: yes

and yes i did the step by step walk through of ZBarSDK and i also tried it in an own project only with the Bar Code Reader and there it is working on the iPhone 5S (Simulator)

Comment: @DavidSteinacher have you tried running your own project on 64-bit device?
**EDIT**:sorry, `on the simulator on the 64-bit device` made me think that your project generates error on the device, not in the simulator

Comment: So, I mean, we can only guess at your problem, since you're not really posting much... but I'm giving you some useful information on how to debug your problem.  Take some backwards steps.  Work backward until it works on the 64-bit device.  Then work forward again until it no longer works.  Try building it after every single line.  Eventually you'll find a specific line that is causing problems.

Comment: ...and when you find that line, you either have it figured out or can ask a more specific question so you can get better help.

Comment: @StasDerpoliuk only on the Simulator because i don't have access to an device. 

it was working without problems till i have imported the ZBarSDK. Then it was said that the ZBarSDK isn't able to run on 64 Bit, so i have set the Architectures to 'no 64-Bit' but since than i am getting the error above.
and i have done every step that i found in other questions/solutions.

Comment: If you'll remove ZBarSDK but leave `no 64-Bit` Architectures, will it build?

**EDIT**: Right now for me it looks like issue with `CocoaPods`.

Comment: @StasDerpoliuk no. same issues.

Comment: Ok, how do you set `no 64-bit`? I've never done it before.

Comment: `target --> build settings --> architectures`: There you can set it to "Standard Architectures (armv7,armv7s)"</br></br>
at the time where i imported "RestKit" with "CocoaPods" it was at the second option "Standard Architectures (including 64-Bit) .. "

Comment: I got it.

Have you tried to set this option to `Standard Architectures (armv7,armv7s)` too?

Comment: thanks it is working :)  

the issue was that the `Cocoa Pod` created 5 targets and at those i forgot to set the option to `Standard Architectures (armv7,armv7s)` too.